# Parcel error: Cannot find module 'tslib'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, parcel

It's been two days and I still can't figure what's wrong here. I've these packages installed: `node-sass`, `autoprefixer`, `parcel-bundler`, and `parcel-plugin-pug`. And my entry point is an `index.pug` file with relative links to `.scss` and `.js` files. The command I used is `parcel src/pug/index.pug --open`. And I'm getting this error:

```
  Cannot find module 'tslib'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:470:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
    at require (/mnt/c/Users/Tyler/Documents/code/parcelapp/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/Tyler/Documents/code/parcelapp/node_modules/parcel-plugin-pug/build/PugAsset.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (/mnt/c/Users/Tyler/Documents/code/parcelapp/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
```

I'm using latest stable versions of node and npm running on WSL (Ubuntu) and I tried deleting `node_modules` folder, reinstalling all the packages, and nothing seem to fix this.

Comment: Installing `tslib` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error in my `angular 5` application when I was running `ng test` command. I had spend hours to fix the same. I have tried,

- Deleting the node_modules folder and then run `npm install` again
- Close and open my `vscode`
- Adding some configuration to `tsconfig`
- Tried running `ng build --prod` which shows some errors and even after fixing them, this error remains same.

But nothing worked for me. All the other commands like `ng build` and `ng serve` were working fine. Then I removed `schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]` from my `TestBed.configureTestingModule({})`, which shows me the real issue.

```
beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, CustomRouterModule,
   FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
   RegisterComponent
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: '/'
   },
   FormBuilder
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
 }).compileComponents();

 componentFixture = TestBed.createComponent(RegisterComponent);
 component = componentFixture.componentInstance;
}));
```

I had to fix them and try `ng test` again. Do you know what, then I was able to run my tests.

It seems like, we get this error when there are some inner errors.

Comment: Thank you sir, you just spared me some hair pulling. I had the same problem while running `ng test`, because I had NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA imported from the wrong place. I was importing from `@angular/core/src/core` when I actually should be importing from `@angular/core`. What a cryptic error message!